# how to output a whole string from char array from pointer which points to structure

Tags: c++, pointers

Shy to ask but I cannot figure out why I get only the first character from `guests->name` in output ? How to print the whole string ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct name_table {
    char name[20];
};

int main(){
    name_table *guests = new name_table;
    cout << "Please enter the the line:";
    cin.get(guests->name, 20);
    cout << "Okay, the line saved: " << *(guests)->name << endl;;

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*(guests)->name
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
|^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
|      |
| guests->name
|      |
|  a char[20]
|      |
| becomes char*
| when passed into
|  operator<<
|
\
dereference
```

Applying dereference to the pointer gives you a single `char`.

**tl;dr: You are printing a single character.**

You can write:

```
guests->name
```

`std::cin` is already clever enough to treat the `char*` as a C-string and iteratively print the *whole* string, character by character.

However, I would advise reading into a `std::string`; in C++ you do not need to mess around with raw character arrays. Also, you have a memory leak and that dynamic allocation is totally needless.

Here's what I'd do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   std::string name_table;
   std::cout << "Please enter the the line: ";
   std::getline(std::cin, name_table);
   std::cout << "Okay, the line saved: " << name_table << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`guests` is a pointer to your struct. In your output `*(guests)->name`, you use both the `*` and the `->` operator, which get evaluated as follows:

- `(guests)->name` first accesses the `name` member of the object behind the pointer `guests`. The parentheses are ignored / optional.
- The so obtained `char` array is then dereferenced using the `*` operator, leading to a single `char`.

So what you really want is one of the following:

- Either remove the `*`, and the parentheses *can* be removed: `guests->name`, like you did in your `cin.get`-line.
- Or put the `*` in the parentheses to dereference `guests` and then use the `.` operator (instead of `->` for accessing the member: `(*guests).name`

Comment: He doesn't _really_ want either of those.

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove * in your count line.

```
cout << "Okay, the line saved: " << (guests)->name << endl;
```